# json arrary cannot prase to kotlin array using modal class

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have a json file which contain some data I am trying to parse this data into kotlin in array using modal class and display in recycler view but unable to get it i share code and jsonfile.

MainActivity

```
  `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val Base_url = "http://192.168.43.163:3000/Users"
lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var recycleradapter:recycleradapter
 var userslist= arrayListOf<Users>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar)
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(Base_url)
        .build()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            var json = response.body!!.string()
            Log.d("Result",json)
            var jsonObject:JSONObject = JSONObject(json)
            var jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Users")
            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                var users= Users(
    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"),  
    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"),
    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("profile") 
    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("profession"))
     userslist.add(users)
            }


            runOnUiThread {

                recycleradapter=recycleradapter(applicationContext as MainActivity,userslist)
                recyclerView.adapter=recycleradapter
                recycleradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

            }
        }

      })
   }
   }`
```

Recycleradapter

```
class recycleradapter(val context:MainActivity,val userlist:ArrayList<Users>): 
RecyclerView.Adapter<recycleradapter.Viewholher>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Viewholher {
   val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false)
    return Viewholher(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Viewholher, position: Int) {
   val view=userlist[position]
    holder.name.text=view.name
    holder.profession.text=view.profession
    Picasso.get().load(view.profile).into(holder.profileImage)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return userlist.size
}

inner class Viewholher(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val name=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name)
    val profession=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.profession)
    val profileImage=view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.profileimage)
}
}
```

modalclass

```
data class Users(
val id: Int,
val name: String,
val profile: String,
val profession: String
)
```

logcat file
2021-07-22 15:19:56.021 15984-15984/com.bazigar.okhttp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2021-07-22 15:19:56.164 15984-16008/com.bazigar.okhttp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: com.bazigar.okhttp, PID: 15984
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"name":"King","id":1,"profession":"Indian politition","profile":"https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png"},{"name":"Queen","id":2,"profession":"Indian politition","profile":"https://futurestud.io/images/books/picasso.png"},{"name":"Wazir","id":3,"profession":"Indian Don","profile":"https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:169)
at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:182)
at com.bazigar.okhttp.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:46)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

[![Json file][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Fhf.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below type in your model class

```
SerializedName("id")
val id : Int
```

Please copy your JSON file and past it on below link editor to convert your JSON to data class in kotlin

https://www.json2kotlin.com/

Hope it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Extend your model class with Parcelable like this

```
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class ModelClass(

    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: Int? = null,

    @Json(name = "Price")
    val price: Int? = null

) : Parcelable
```

Here is an example of parcelable model